# How can I remove rectangular contour and extract text with OpenCV for pytesseract on an image?

Tags: python, opencv, text-extraction

I want to extract the text from this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AASU.png). I tried removing the rectangle contour so I started detecting the horizontal and vertical lines that form the boxes. But I found a problem where some characters pixels were mistakenly identified as vertical lines.
to obtain a clean image without the rectangle boxes, containing only the line texts, so I can then apply pytesseract for text extraction.

Can you help with any suggestions to remove the rectangular boxes?

Thank you!

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

image = io.imread("sample.png")
result = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

#Remove horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (40,1))
remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)
plt.imshow(result)
```

[removing horizontal lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpte7.png)

```
# Remove vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,40))
remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)

plt.imshow(result)
```

[removing horizontal and vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXjMJ.png)

Comment: Beware that you are mixing PIL and OpenCV and the two aren't (and shouldn't be) 100% compatible. Get contours and filter them by aspect ratio (width/height) and area. Remove all contours that are rectangle-shaped (wider than "tall") and are bigger than a certain area threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find connected components in the image and filter out those that are too wide or tall.
For example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

im=cv2.imread('0AASU.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im_monochrome=cv2.threshold(im, 127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
_, labels,stats,_=cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(im_monochrome)
idx=np.nonzero((stats[:,2]>150) | (stats[:,3]>150)) # select CC with h>150 or w>150 px.
result=255*np.uint8(np.isin(labels, idx)) # remove this CC
cv2.imwrite( 'result.png', result)
```

[image]